# how to choose what value loops first in a while loop

Tags: python, sql, database

So i have an array and i want to append certain values to it in a while loop but i want them in a certain order. It's something like this:

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5]
count = -1
while count < 2:
    for x in num:
        c.execute('SELECT column FROM table WHERE restriction = %s;', (x + count,))
        rows = c.fetchall()
        array = []
        for row in rows:
            array.append(row[0])
    count += 1
```

but i want the values where count = 0 to go first in the array

I know i can just split it up but is there any way to do it in this format and keep it short?

EDIT: Don't worry about the code itself as its just an example and not the code i am using i just want to know if i can loop count = 0 first and then count = -1 and then count = 1 so that in the final array, the results from count = 0 will be first in the list.

Comment: This is confusing. Can you further explain your question?

Comment: "any way to do it in this format " your code seems to be incomplete or just incorrect, so the format prbably would need to change. For example. in the first for you have `array = []`. Thus, for each iteration of x, array is reset. You will not have access to any rows from previous iteration. Also shouldn't `rows = c.fetchall` be ` rows = c.fetchall()`?

Comment: If I understand that code correctly, the loop will iterate count from -1 to 1, which is odd. It will select `where restriction = 0` then `2` then `4`, which is also odd.  Is that what you meant to do?  If so, it's a bit tortured.  What's the purpose?

Comment: @Schwern  no, you missed x + count, so it will select where restriction = 0 through 4, then where restriction = 1 through 5, then where restriction = 2 through 6.  But still very odd because the 2nd iteration is the one the OP wants to insert at the front of the array.

Comment: Oh, then `counts = [0, -1, 1]` and `for count in counts` instead of the outer while loop.  Turning the inner loop into a method, as suggested in the answer, makes this more obvious.

Comment: @Schwern yeah great idea thanks i was really tired when posting this so that's probably why i didn't realize this and made it this confusing so thanks

Comment: @Schwern Yes, that's what the code is doing, still bizarre though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve something like this. In the main loop, only store the items in array if count == 0. Otherwise put them into a temporary array. Then after the main loop finishes, move the temporary stuff to the end of the main array. But your code is still a poor solution* and without knowing what you are trying to achieve, this is the best I can provide.

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5]
count = -1
array = []
tempArray = []

while count < 2:
    for x in num:
        c.execute('SELECT column FROM table WHERE restriction = %s;', (x + count,))
        rows = c.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            if count == 0:
                array.append(row)
            else:
                tempArray.append(row)
    count += 1

for item in tempArray:
     array.append(item)
```

*I say poor solution because your code is so hard to understand. I am guessing you are trying to do this:

```
array = []

for x in range(5):
    c.execute('SELECT column FROM table WHERE restriction = %s;', (x + 1)
    rows = c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        array.append(row)

# now get your remaining data
```

I think what you really need to do is write a method:

```
def getRows(x):
    c.execute('SELECT column FROM table WHERE restriction = %s;', (x)
    rows = c.fetchall()
    return rows

for count in range(4):
    array.append(getRows(count + 1))

for count in range(4):
    array.append(getRows(count))

for count in range(4)
    array.append(getRows(count + 2))
```

which you can then rewrite as:

```
def getRows(x):
    c.execute('SELECT column FROM table WHERE restriction = %s;', (x)
    rows = c.fetchall()
    return rows

def addToArray(modifier):
   for count in range(4)
       array.append(getRows(count + modifier))
```

and then call it 3 times:

```
   addToArray(1)
   addToArray(0)
   addToArray(2)
```